# Explosion de materiales de una receta acomodada por tipo ingrediente

Tags: excel

Hay alguna manera de convertir la tabla siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acomodada a traves de una tabla dinamica o una formula a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder agregar cada vez un nuevo pastel y se integre automaticamente a cada Fila

Comment: Hola Luis. Esta pregunta es demasiado amplia. Deberías intentar tu algo y si te atascas o salen errores preguntar. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias, lo tomare a consideracion